# Casting a list of children to a list of parent types

Tags: c#, .net

For brevity, I will be generic here. I have a base class - Review - that has a child - ShelfAwarenessReview.

I also have a method, whose signature is required by an interface:

```
public List<Review> GetReviews(string filePath)
        {
            XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(filePath);

            var dtos = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("message")
                       select new ShelfAwarenessReview()
                       {
                           PubDate = item.Element("meta").Attribute("permlinkdate").Value,
                           Summary = item.Element("meta").Element("summary").Value,
                           Isbn = item.Element("BookInfo").Element("ISBN").Value
                       };

            List<Review> reviews = new List<Review>();
            reviews = dtos.ToList();

            return reviews;
        }
```

Now, the error I am getting is that `List<ShelfAwarenessReview>` cannot be cast implicitly to `List<Review>`.

I have tried several types of casting - or, at least I thought I did - and it doesn't work. I thought because ShelfAwarenessReview is a child of Review that this would work. After all, as the inheritance adage goes, "All toasters are appliances but not all appliances are toasters"...

**What do I need to do to get a list of ShelfAwarenessReviews to exit the method in as a list of its parent type (Review)?**

Just an FYI, the code calling this method is intended not to care about the types reviews it is getting. The subsequent code will operate on whatever.

I appreciate it big time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well to start with, you don't need to create an empty `List<Review>` which you then ignore :)

Here's the simplest solution:

```
public List<Review> GetReviews(string filePath)
{
    XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(filePath);

    var dtos = ...; // As before

    return dtos.Cast<Review>().ToList();
}
```

If you're using .NET 4 and C# 4, there's another alternative due to generic covariance which works for `IEnumerable<T>` but not `List<T>`:

```
public List<Review> GetReviews(string filePath)
{
    XElement xmlDoc = XElement.Load(filePath);

    IEnumerable<Review> dtos = ...; // As before

    return dtos.ToList();
}
```

Note the explicit specification of the type of `dtos`. The query expression will be of type `IEnumerable<ShelfAwarenessReview>` but that's implicitly convertible (in C# 4) to `IEnumerable<Review>`.

Comment: Bless you, kind sir. Damn. I need to get better at understanding covariance and up-casting. You were first, so you get my check of approval. Thanks a billion.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
reviews = dtos.ToList();
```

To:

```
reviews = dtos.Cast<Review>().ToList();
```

The problem is that List and List are not covariant. It's easy to understand if you think about it:

```
List<ShelfAwarenessReview> initial = new List<ShelfAwarenessReview>();
List<Review> cast = (List<Review>)initial;

// The underlying type is still List<ShelfAwarenessReview>.
// SomeOtherReview inherits Review but not ShelfAwarenessReview
// What will happen when I make the following call?
cast.Add(new SomeOtherReview());
```

Comment: @JustinNiesnner So many posted the answer already, but thank you for your input. +1 for the effort, though :).

Answer (score 3):

Use Cast to convert to base type:

```
return dtos.Cast<Review>().ToList();
```

Comment: So many posted the answer already, but thank you for your input. +1 for the effort, though :

Answer (score 3):

It's the problem of [Covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx). For your particular problem, try:

```
return dtos.ToList().Cast<Review>();
```

Comment: So many posted the answer already, but thank you for your input. +1 for the effort, though :

Answer (score 1):

use this one

```
  List<Review> reviews = dtos.Cast<Review>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a List to List. Suppose you could, horrible things would happen:

```
List<String> list = new list<String>();
list.Add("Hello");
List<Object> list2 = List<Object>(list);
list2.Add(12);
```

Huh? Did I just add an integer to a list of strings. That's why you can't. You should read about covariance and contravariance.

Comment: I see your point. Thanks for the example. I know some things were solves with .NET 4 for co/contra variance. I do indeed need to learn more about this. I am still looking for sources on it as well. Thanks again for the example.

Comment: No problem, read this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Review> reviews = dtos.Cast<Review>().ToList();
```