# Inheritance and ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a Windows Phone 8 application.

I have this class:

```
public class LocationToShow : ARItem
```

And, these two collections:

```
ObservableCollection<ARItem> arItems;
ObservableCollection<LocationToShow> locations;
```

When I do this:

```
arItems = locations;
```

I get the following error:

```
Can't convert implicity the type ObservableCollection<LocationToShow> into the type ObservableCollection<ARItem>
```

But if I do this:

```
arItems = (ObservableCollection<ARItem>)locations;
```

I get this error:

```
Can't convert the type ObservableCollection<LocationToShow> into the type ObservableCollection<ARItem>
```

**How can I fix this problem?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You can use `IEnumerable` instead of `ObservableCollection`

```
IEnumerable<ARItem> arItems;
IEnumerable<LocationToShow> locations;
arItems = locations;
```

2) User `Cast<>` Extension method

```
var tempCollection = locations.Cast<ARItem>();
arItems.Clear();
tempCollection.ToList().ForEach(li=>arItems.Add(li));
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to generics you cannot just assign a derived type to a base type. Why? This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157826/casting-a-list-of-children-to-a-list-of-parent-types#answer-8157864) gives a great reason why.

To assign generics of derived type to generics of base type you use [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517).

Try:

```
ObservableCollection<Derived> arItems = new ObservableCollection<Derived>();
IEnumerable<Base> locations = new ObservableCollection<Base>();
locations = arItems;
```